# inputProps vs InputProps in Material UI TextField

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textfield

What are the differences between `inputProps` and `InputProps`? The 2 `TextField`s below do the same thing. When do I have to choose one over the other?

```
<TextField
  label="inputProps"
  inputProps={{
    name: 'inputProps',
    type: 'number',
    placeholder: 'placeholder',
    value,
    onChange: handleChange,
  }}
/>
```

```
<TextField
  label="InputProps"
  InputProps={{
    name: 'InputProps',
    type: 'number',
    placeholder: 'placeholder',
    value,
    onChange: handleChange,
  }}
/>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`InputProps` applies to `Input` react-component [since](https://mui.com/components/text-fields/#components):

> TextField is composed of smaller components ( FormControl, Input, FilledInput, InputLabel, OutlinedInput, and FormHelperText ) that you can leverage directly to significantly customize your form inputs.

`inputProps` applies to what will be `input` DOM-element and it gets all of its [attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attributes).

Therefore, if it's necessary to change something that has to do with an `input` being a React component (eg. set an `Icon`) we should use `InputProps`. For all other changes which aren't controlled by [Input component properties](https://mui.com/api/input/) there's a variety of [input attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attributes).

Comment: Nice answer, thanks for the explanation!

Comment: jesus christ, why isn't this just in the docs. so much crap like this in MUI. I wish I wasn't forced to use it

Comment: @ortonomy what would you prefer to use?

Comment: You will not be able to use both. `No duplicate props allowed  react/jsx-no-duplicate-props
`

Comment: @Vikas, I regularly use both without issue.  There must be something wrong with your setup. Javascript is case sensitive, so `inputProps` and `InputProps` are not duplicates. Note that one has a capital letter at the beginning.

Comment: if you get the error no duplicate props allowed, you can put the lowercase inputProps inside of the uppercase InputProps.