# how to add icon to Autocomplete TextField MUI v5 in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

Well, I made an autocomplete using the code below and tried to display its icon after selecting each item, but it didn't work!

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import { TextField,InputAdornment ,Autocomplete,Box} from '@mui/material';
import v1 from './v1.svg';
import  v3 from './v2.svg';
import  v4 from './v3.svg';
import  v4 from './v4.svg';
function App() {
   const [useicon ,setUseicon]=useState(v1);
   const options=[
      {'label':"تتر","icon":v1},
      {'label':"بایننس",'icon':v2},
      {'label':"بی اس دی",'icon':v3},
      {'label':"دای",'icon':v4},
   ]
  return (
   <div>
   
       <Autocomplete
        options={options}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label}
        onChange={(e,value)=>{setUseicon(value['icon'])}}
        sx={{width:"300px"}}
        renderOption={(props, option) => (
          <Box component="li" {...props}>
            <img src={option.icon} style={{width:"50px",height:"50px"}} alt={option.label} />
            {option.label}
          </Box>
        )}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            inputProps={{
              ...params.inputProps,
              startAdornment: <InputAdornment position='end'>
                    <img src={useicon} />
              </InputAdornment>  ,
            }}
          />
        )}
       />
   </div>
 )
}
 export default App;
```

some notes:

1-All the imports were correct and there is no problem

2-In the same way, the icon is shown in the TextField Component.

3-If there is a typo, know that it was in this post and not in the program itself

Please help because it is very important for me.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `inputProps` with `InputProps`.

```
InputProps={{
  ...params.InputProps,
  startAdornment: (
    <InputAdornment position='end'>
      <img src={useicon} />
    </InputAdornment>  
  ),
}}
```

`inputProps` is the attributes You apply to the `input` Dom element, but the `InputProps` is the properties that You assign to the MUI `Input` element.
More data [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69870930/inputprops-vs-inputprops-in-mui-textfield).

Comment: thank you ,but found another way!

Comment: @Ammar Please share it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the popupIcon prop available on the Autocomplete component.

```js
<Autocomplete
  options={[]}
  popupIcon={<Chevron />} <-- place svg here
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField {...params} />
  )}
/>
```

If you need to use it in multiple places you can customize it using the theme file:

```js
MuiAutocomplete: {
  defaultProps: {
    popupIcon: <Chevron />,
  },
  styleOverrides: {
    root: {
     
    },
  },
},
```